# Issue counting rows in different files using different filters

Tags: unix

Issue to calculate the count of records excluding any headers in the files.  In some files there are 2-3 headers (same header name) and others only one.

Below EGREP works fine for most but one file (F220.) it gives less count though '$' symbol is not available in header or data.

Command used:

```
srccount=`egrep -cv '[#$]|georgia:|Order|F220.' $FILE`
```

These statements works fine for the file (F220.) not sure why???

1. `` srccount=`egrep -cv ' [#$]|georgia:|Order|F220.' $FILE` `` - space before `[]`
2. `` srccount=`egrep -cv '[#]|georgia:|Order|F220.' $FILE` `` - `$` symbol is removed but cause mismatch if file 4 has $

Example:

```
File 1 - header has F220.fieldname1
File 2 - header has georgia:fieldname1, georgia:fieldname2
File 3 - header has Order.fieldname1
File 4 - header has # or $ like Wed $ or Wed #
```

Any help using EGREP or AWK/SED would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post te output of `head -5 F220` and `head -5 F220| egrep -v '[#$]|georgia:|Order|F220.'`.